# Polymorphic coersion to Word64 in Standard ML

Tags: sml, smlnj, polyml, mlton

I would like create a polymorphic function that converts 8,16,32 bit words into 64 bit word. How can I do it?

### UPDATE1

In the basis library all word structures have functions `toLarge` and `fromLarge` to convert to/from the `LargeWord`, which is as far as I understand just a synonym for Word32.

### UPDATE2

According to the spec, word size must be power of two, but in SML/NJ I have

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.84 [built: Mon Dec 03 10:23:14 2018]
- Word.wordSize;
val it = 31 : int
- Word32.wordSize;
val it = 32 : int
- Word.toLarge;
val it = fn : word -> Word32.word
> LargeWord.wordSize;
val it = 32 : int
```

while in PolyML

```
Poly/ML 5.7.1 Release
> Word.wordSize;
val it = 63: int
> Word64.wordSize;
val it = 64: int
> Word.toLarge;
val it = fn: word -> ?.word
> LargeWord.wordSize;
val it = 64: int
```

How is that? Why `Word.wordSize` is not power of two? And why `Word` representation differs in these SML implementations?

### UPDATE3

Actually, I want to be able "promote" smaller words into the larger ones using (<<) operator, but cannot figure it out how to do it.

### UPDATE4

It seems that `Word` and `LargeWord` depend on the architecture and represent a machine word. Because SML/NJ does not support 64-bit arch, it has different word size.

Comment: Can somebody explain what `Word` struct does mean in contrast with `LargeWord`? It seems to be `Word.wordSize = LargeWord.wordSize - 1`

Comment: I can't find where in [the definition of SML](http://sml-family.org/sml97-defn.pdf) that word size must be a power of two. And yes, `Word` and `LargeWord` are system and compiler dependent, so that's super confusing. SML/NJ does have `Word64`, but `LargeWord` doesn't seem to have been updated along with its introduction. `<<` is specific to a certain word type; it's only overloaded for `0w...` literals, so it doesn't work for coersion. See my answer for suggestions.

Comment: LargeWord has to be a synonym for the Word structure with the largest wordSize in a given system. SML/NJ doesn't satisfy the spec. I believe this was meant as a transitionary thing (introduced in 2004, according to the [change log](https://www.smlnj.org/dist/working/110.84/HISTORY.html)), but never rectified.

Comment: Sorry, by "spec" I meant docs: http://sml-family.org/Basis/word.html. By the way, why `Word.wordSize` is `31/63`, whereas `LargeWord.wordSize` is `32/64`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in that the types `Word8.word`, `Word32.word` and `Word64.word` only share the common type `'a` which cannot generally be converted a `Word64.word` via *parametric polymorphism*.

The exact function you are looking for *could* (and *should*) have been:

```
Word<N>.toLargeWord : word -> LargeWord.word
```

Unfortunately, as you have discovered, it appears that `LargeWord.word` is an alias to `Word32` and not `Word64` in SML/NJ. It doesn't look like *Basis* specifies that `LargeWord.word` *must* do this, but reality. In Poly/ML it appears that `LargeWord.wordSize` is 126 and in Moscow ML there is no `LargeWord` structure! Sigh. But at least in Poly/ML it can contain a `Word64.word`.

In light of this, I'd suggest one of two things:

1. You can use *ad-hoc polymorphism*: Since all three modules share the signature [`WORD`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/word.html) and this signature holds, among other things:

   ```
   val toLargeInt : word -> LargeInt.int
   ```

   So a hack may be to convert to a `LargeInt.int` and then down to a `Word64.word`: You can build a *functor* that takes one module with the `WORD` signature and return a structure that contains the conversion to `Word64`.

   ```
   functor ToWord64 (WordN : WORD) = struct
       fun toWord64 (n : WordN.word) : Word64.word =
           Word64.fromLargeInt (WordN.toLargeInt n)
   end
   ```

   You can then instantiate this functor for each of your cases:

   ```
   structure Word8ToWord64 = ToWord64(Word8)

   val myWord64 = Word8ToWord64.toWord64 myWord8
   ```

   This is a bit messy and the hierarchy of existing modules that includes `LargeWord` was meant to avoid it.
2. Alternatively, if you'd rather avoid this extra functor and arbitrary-precision integers as an intermediate representation, since this is both inefficient and unnecessary, you could change your standard library's `LargeWord :> WORD` so that it assumes the use of `Word64` instead.

This could have been avoided if the standard library had been written in a functorial style with `LargeWord` having/being a parameter fixed somewhere where you could override it. But it would also make the standard library more complex.

With regards to ML module system design, I think the choice of placing `toLargeWord` in the `WORD` signature is one approach which is very convenient because you don't need a lot of functor instances, but, as you have witnessed, not very extensible. You can see the different philosophies applied in Jane Street's OCaml libraries Base and Core, where in Core you have e.g. `Char.Map.t` (convenient) and in Base you have `Map.M(Char).t` (extensible).

*I've assumed that your words are all unsigned.*

Comment: I my machine with Poly v5.7.1 LargeWord.wordSize is 64.

Answer (score 1):

I concluded, that there's no way to make this in polymorphic way. Instead, have to use an appropriate `toLarge/fromLarge` methods like this:

```
fun toWord64 (w : Word8.word) : Word64.word = Word64.fromLarge (Word8.toLarge w)
```

I could use `toLarge` directly, but I want to ensure that resulting value will be `Word64`. This will compile with SML/NJ, but call of this function will cause a runtime exception.

By the way, I did not find a way how to extract Word64 from byte array in 32-bit SML/NJ.